# By default in asp.net web forms it will have two aspNetHidden Divs, How do I remove that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

When i create a empty webform page in asp.net it create the code like below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Threetier.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

additionally i added googleapis jquery in head tag using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, this means that it has only one div in form and  when I console the below code I should get object of one div:

```
$("#form1").find('div');
```

but the result is

```
Object[div.aspNetHidden, div.aspNetHidden, div ]
```

Comment: How are you determining that result?

Comment: I just run  " $("#form1").find('div'); " in firebug console.

Comment: Inspect your page and check how many divs are there.

Comment: I see three Divs <div class="aspNetHidden">..</div>,<div class="aspNetHidden">..</div> and <div> </div>.

Comment: That's why you are getting more than one div in result

Comment: Yeah!!., I am just wondering how I can remove those two aspNetHidden divs , so that  later if I want to select any paragraph using jquery in any div i can count the div number and select the paragraph number accordingly, i hope i am making sense.

Comment: You can assign `id` and if multiple elements need to be selected you can use class and select them by class name. Suppose a class is used by 3 paragraph when you will access elements by classname you will get 3

Comment: I totally agree and i knew this, but is there any way that I can remove those aspNetHidden divs and proceed by counting the divs and then do my things.

Comment: Yes you can check if div has class `aspNetHidden` ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
$("#form1").find('div').not('.aspNetHidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

More precisely if you want to select particular div just say we want to select the first div here then:

```
 $("#form1").find('div').not('.aspNetHidden').eq(0);
```

this will return the first div in the form with `id='form1'`.